# Firebase observe new added data even when the function isn't called

Tags: swift, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

I have a function that observes data from my Firebase database. This data will be inserted in an array, so it can be send to my tableviewcell Viewcontroller. All the data will be put correct in the tabelviewcell, but I have a problem when I update my Firebase database. Everytime I change a value in the database it will immediately update my tableView even when my function is not called. I am not sure what I am doing wrong and how to prevent this.

This is my function observe:

```
Database.database().reference().child("posts").child("\(postId)").child("comments").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
   if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
     for snap in snapshots {
       if let postDict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
          let key = snap.key
          let post = Comment.transformComment(dict: postDict)
          self.comments.insert(post, at: 0)
          self.tableView.reloadData()
       }
     }
   }
})
```

Array:

```
var comments: [Comment] = []

extension Comment {
    static func transformComment(dict: [String: Any]) -> Comment {
        let comment = Comment()
        comment.commentText = dict["commentText"] as? String
        comment.uid = dict["uid"] as? String
        comment.timestamp = dict["timestamp"] as? Int
        comment.likeCount = dict["likeCount"] as? Int
        comment.childByAutoId = dict["childByAutoId"] as? String
        comment.id = dict["postId"] as? String
        return comment
    }
}
```

Tablevieww Functions:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if comments.count == 0 {
            self.tableView.setEmptyMessage("No comments yet!")
        } else {
            self.tableView.restore()
        }
        return comments.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Comment", for: indexPath) as! CommentTableViewCell
        let comment = comments[indexPath.row]
        cell.comment = comment
        cell.delegate = self

        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To listen once replace

```
.child("comments").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
```

With

```
.child("comments").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in
```

Or

```
.child("comments").observe(.childChanged) { snapshot  in
```

to listen to added childs